# How to enable direct message in twitter integration on sunshine conversation?

Tags: zendesk, smooch, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I have allowed direct message in my twitter account but on sunshine it still showing direct message is disabled in twitter integration. So can anyone help me how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate via the Sunshine Conversations Dashboard, you'll need to reach out to the support team, since there's a Billing component to using Twitter DM: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/twitter/#using-the-dashboard

You can also signup for access to Twitter's `Accounts Activity API` directly and then use the API to integrate to Sunshine Conversations: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/twitter/#using-the-integration-api